# Is there a way to configure Nlog in C# and write to Db?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I am using NLog 4.6.6 and NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.8.4 and i am writing the below configuration in Program.cs of a ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core 2.2). My internal-nlog.txt is writing with no Errors with the below configuration but in the db the NLog does not logs. My need is to configure NLog into the C# at runtime and not in a configuration file.

```
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget() { FileName = "Logs\\internal-nlog.txt", Name = "logfile", Layout = "${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" };
        var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget() { Name = "logconsole", Layout = "${message}" };
        var logmemory = new NLog.Targets.MemoryTarget() { Name = "logmemory", Layout = "${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" };

        config.AddTarget(logfile);
        config.AddTarget(logconsole);
        config.AddTarget(logmemory);

        DatabaseTarget databaseTarget = new DatabaseTarget();
        DatabaseParameterInfo param;

        databaseTarget.ConnectionString = "Server=xxxx;Database=xxxx; User ID=xxxx; Password=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;";
        databaseTarget.Name = "db";
        databaseTarget.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        databaseTarget.CommandText = "[dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p]";
        databaseTarget.DBProvider = "mssql";

        param = new DatabaseParameterInfo();
        param.Name = "@requestIp";
        param.Layout = "${aspnet-request-ip:CheckForwardedForHeader}";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new DatabaseParameterInfo();
        param.Name = "@logged";
        param.Layout = "${date}";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new DatabaseParameterInfo();
        param.Name = "@level";
        param.Layout = "${level}";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new DatabaseParameterInfo();
        param.Name = "@level";
        param.Layout = "${level}";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new DatabaseParameterInfo();
        param.Name = "@message";
        param.Layout = "${message}";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new DatabaseParameterInfo();
        param.Name = "@logger";
        param.Layout = "${logger}";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new DatabaseParameterInfo();
        param.Name = "@properties";
        param.Layout = "${all-event-properties:separator=|}";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new DatabaseParameterInfo();
        param.Name = "@callsite";
        param.Layout = "${callsite}";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new DatabaseParameterInfo();
        param.Name = "@exception";
        param.Layout = "${exception:tostring}";
        databaseTarget.Parameters.Add(param);

        config.AddTarget("DatabaseTarget", databaseTarget);

        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Debug, logconsole));
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Debug, logfile));
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Debug, logmemory));
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Debug, databaseTarget));

        LogManager.Configuration = config;

        var logFactory = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(config);
        var logger = logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        logger.Error( "This is my Test Log.");      //Does Not Log to DB
```

Comment: Have you tried [enabling internal logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) to see if it gives you any indications why it is not working?

Comment: Depending on your needs there is also an option to prepare several config files (e.g. one for production and one for test environment) and load the file that you need at runtime.

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target).